# Cannot open source file avr/io.h (dependency of hal.h) with Visual Studio Code on windows 10

Tags: embedded, visual-studio-code

I want to implement an embedded project using stm32F0 (arm-based) with VS Code. The project ran properly on other systems.

1. I Added C/C++ extension to visual studio
2. I installed a compiler for cortex-m0 arm: GNU Arm Embedded toolchain/gcc arm for windows.
3. Makefiles installed: binaries file + dependencies file
4. openOCD installed (open On Chip Debugger)
5. tasks.json (build instructions), c_cpp_properties.json (compiler path and IntelliSense settings) were created. I modified the Include path because my program includes header files that aren't in my workspace, and that is not in the standard library path.

c_cpp_properties.json file

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**" ,
                "C:\\Users\\lib\\chibios\\ChibiOS-313416b8fda90d9973a749a0a35970956852c286\\os\\hal\\include",
                "C:\\Users\\lib\\chibios\\ChibiOS-313416b8fda90d9973a749a0a35970956852c286\\os\\common\\ports\\ARM\\compilers\\GCC",
                "C:\\Users\\lib\\chibios\\ChibiOS-313416b8fda90d9973a749a0a35970956852c286\\os\\nil\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "E:\\tools-vs\\gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major\\bin\\arm-none-eabi-g++", 
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-arm",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "E:\\tools-vs\\gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major\\lib\\gcc\\arm-none-eabi\\10.2.1\\include"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

After adding these paths, I still got errors:

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit

> cannot open source file "avr/io.h" (dependency of "hal.h")

As an embedded project has lots of libraries and dependencies, it is not possible to add paths of dependencies one by one. After solving and adding a path for one dependency, there should be another error.

Another problem is that I cannot even find the dependency avr/io.h by myself in the directory.

I used Keil before for other projects. When I compiled the code, it called all dependencies by itself. Before compiling, I didn't see dependencies on the tree section or any error for dependencies of header files.

- But, how VS Code can find dependencies before compiling?
- I also was wondering if I should add a path for main.cpp file and other C and CPP files in the configuration file of VS Code to solve these problems?
- For debugging, I don't see any debugger in the list, though I installed openOCD and add the path in the environment variable

Much appreciated for any command or helpful resource, in advance.

Comment: Why would your ARM Cortex-M0 code have a dependency or a header for an entirely different architecture? Most likely you have some conditional compilation and have not set the required target configuration macros. VSCode can parse the code in the project just like a compiler. It won't stop you from building, but the build may result in similar errors. The context in the code would be far more useful than information about your development environment. I.e around where avr/io.h" is included in "hal.h"

Comment: I would guess that the fill diagnostic given will take you to the exact location io/avr.h is included and the issue will be obvious.  Most likley your ChibiOS port is not for STM32 (in http://chibios.sourceforge.net/docs3/hal/mcuconf_8h_source.html perhaps?)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thank you for the answers.

- Using Visual Studio instead of Visual Studio Code
- Using the right toolchains (GCC: gcc-arm-none-eabi)
- adding visualGDB plugin from sysProgs to VS
- having IntelliSense configuration (The extension in VS finds paths after checking default location & uses the compiler we have on the pc to configure IntelliSense. If there is an error in include files, you can edit the IntelliSense to tell the C++ extension where the compiler is and include header files. But visualGDB will automatically find them)
- having include paths configured
- building the project
- and rescanning solution

All of these steps solved the problem for me.

Comment: But the question was specifically how to get it to work in VS Code and your solution is to abandon it, so strictly this is no an answer to the question.  This is problem _avoidance_ not _solution_.  That is fine, but someone looking for a VS Code solution based on the title will find this less than helpful.  BTW do not edit the question to mark it "solved".  There is a big green tick next to the question for that.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot open source file avr/io.h (dependency of hal.h)

You appear to be using ChibiOS whhich has a file hal.h which includes halconf.h which includes mcuconf.h.  Clearly you appear to have an AVR port of ChibiOS where you need STM32 or ARM Cortex-M support.

> But, how VS Code can find dependencies before compiling?

The same way as the compiler/pre-processor do, by having include paths configured, parsing the project files and accounting for any externally defined (command line) macros.

> I also was wondering if I should add a path for main.cpp file and other C and CPP files in the configuration file of VS Code to solve these problems?

I believe it will parse project files in any case.  It only needs to find the header files included in a source file to provide context for the parsing of the sourcefile.

> For debugging, I don't see any debugger in the list, though I installed openOCD and add the path in the environment variable

That is an entirely different question - post a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have code for 8-bits AVR microcontrollers and you try to directly compile it using ARM toolchain. It will not work. You will need to rewrite this program (not only includes, but almost everything. Interrupt handlers, registers, even hardware architecture differs (Harvard/von Neumann)).

For the beginner, it is mission impossible.